# Two buttons doing same action in my perl CGI script

Tags: perl, redirect, button, cgi

I have this 2 buttons in my perl cgi code which does the same action even I have assigned different actions to each button
Here is the code

```
print
  start_html(),
  start_form(-action => 'com.pl'),         #first action for first button
  submit(-name => 'submit', -value => 'View com.pl'), //on cliking this redirects to com.pl script

  start_form(-action => 'about.pl'),
  submit(-name => 'submit', -value => 'About Us');  //On clicking this button it redirects to com.l instead about.pl

  end_form,
  end_html;
```

How can I change this so that on clicking on about us button will redirect me to about.pl

Comment: Create two forms with a button each

Comment: @ikegami I tried it, but in that case it works, but Two buttons will come one below other. I don't want it to be 1 below other. I want it to be in same row

Comment: If you can't figure out how to place your two forms side by side (table, abs positioning, floating, etc), you'll need to use JS to change the form's action.

Comment: Don't produce your HTML with CGI.pm. Use a template system instead.

Answer (score 3):

As I see the problem is that You start a `<FORM>` twice, but You close it only once! So You have a `FORM` and (I assume) only the first will be activated if a `SUBMIT` button is pressed as the second `FORM` is considered as mistake.

Please post the `HTML` page source from your browser. This can help to analyse the result.

I suggest to implement the `onClick` action for both buttons. So you can launch any script you want.

Answer (score 2):

HTML only allows a `<form>` to have one `action`. If you want to have separate `action`s, you need to either have separate forms or use javascript to change the form's action just before submission.

The more common way of getting the same effect is to have only a single (base) URL that all form submissions go to, with the different buttons giving different values to an "action" parameter.  The code receiving the submission then examines this parameter to determine what to do.

The more advanced (and easier) version of this common way is to use a web framework (my personal preference is [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/)) to handle the process of determining what action was requested and dispatching the request to the proper `sub` to deal with it.

All that aside, even if you do stick with CGI.pm instead of using a "real" framework, I would advise against using CGI.pm's HTML-generation functions.  Including them in CGI.pm is generally recognized as a Bad Idea these days.  Using a template system (such as [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/module/Template) or [Xslate](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aXslate)) is a much more flexible and maintainable approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using a form to do this. If all you want is two form like buttons next to each other. Then I would use CSS with a hyperlink.

```
<style>
a.button5 {
-webkit-appearance: button;
-moz-appearance: button;
appearance: button;

text-decoration: none;
color: initial;
}
</style>
<a class="button5" href="com.pl">View com.pl</a> &nbsp;<a class="button5" href="about.pl">About Us</a>
```